# Why does the serial.test function from the vars package in R yield contradictory results for type='BG', 'ES', and 'PT.asymptotic'?

Tags: r, autocorrelation, vector-autoregression, diagnostic

I fitted a VAR model, individually all the residuals do not have autocorrelation, but if I use the serial.test I get different results:

1. Type 'ES' Edgerton and Shukur (1999) Test p.value=0.99
2. Type 'BG' Breusch-Godfrey LM-statistic Test p.value=0.45
3. Type 'PT.asymptotic'Portmanteau statistic  p.value=3.442e-15

I understand that all three tests have the same null hypothesis:
HO. No autocorrelation

Comment: If these are different tests, why should they give the same result? Apparently, they are sensitive to different patterns in the data. The p-values that differ quite a bit tell you the different patterns can be measured precisely enough to reject H0 in case 3 but not in the other two cases.